# Amazon DynamoDB row-level authorization non unique ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, access-control

According to this [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/) i try to implement Amazon DynamoDB row-level authorization on my dynamoDB table,

According to the post i have to implement a condition in the IAM policy,
use this policy to to create the role which will authenticate, like this :

```
"ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
              "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
        ]
}
```

it's clear, but there's a thing :

each user will have a unique Identiy ID, so if i create items using this unique Identity ID, in the Dynamodb it will not be unique, if the user will put more than one item

According to the post we have this image :

[image]

So i'm wondering if i didn't miss something out there, i want Amazon DynamoDB row-level authorization so each user can only query all the items he stores, and users can stores more than one item.

i've thaught to use a different sort ID, but is it the right thing to do ?

Comment: I would assume that every item has a partition key and sort key. The partition key identifies the user while the sort key identifies the item (perhaps it's an ID of some sort or a GUID). The combination of partition key and sort key uniquely identifies a given item for a given user. The partition key alone identifies all items for a given user.

Comment: Generally, you should not let users directly query your database. If you have a service that users must go through to get data, then you can easily implement your required behavior in your service.

Answer (score 2):

If your users should be allowed more than one item in the table, you just need to specify a sort key (range key).

Each item in a table must have a unique primary key, which is composed of the partition key and optionally a sort key.

The nature of the sort key will depend on entirely on the items you wish to store. Clearly each item you store must have a unique combination of partition key and sort key.